# PHP: \n \r \t won't work on double qoutes

Tags: php, string, escaping, echo, double-quotes

Using PHP 5.6.2 on MAMP PRO and trying to echo this string of characters:

```
echo " \" \n \r \t \\ \$ ";
```

The output that I get is:

```
" \ $
```

So escape sequences such as \n \t \r are neglected. I don't know if there's something wrong with php.ini because it has been working fine before.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to fix this.

Comment: doing this in Terminal, everything works. maybe it's the representation of these characters in the browser, if you're using MAMP.

Comment: What tool do you use to have a look at the output? Browsers will just show you a space for all whitespace characters unless you use them in `<pre>` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In browser

```
echo "<pre> \" \n \r \t \\ \$ </pre>";
```

In terminal

```
echo " \" \n \r \t \\ \$ ";
```

---

### pre

The HTML  Element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad because browsers output just a whitespace for all whitespaces (newline, tab, return) unless you use <pre>.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for echo statement and double for \t or \n.

Something like that:

```
echo 'Your text' . "\t" .
     'Your text' . "\n" .
     'Your text at next line';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `PHP_EOL` constant when executing script in terminal. For web browsers `<br />` should be used